# Python ES2CSV -elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400, u'search_phase_execution_exception', u'compile error')

Tags: python, csv, elasticsearch

what i am trying   `es2csv  -u http://localhost:9200/ -r -q '{ "query": {"match_all": {}},"script_fields":{"field_name": {"script": {"source": "calculations","lang": "painless" }}}}' -i index -f field_name  --debug -o output.csv`

but its giving me error

```
File "/usr/bin/es2csv", line 8, in <module>
sys.exit(main())
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/es2csv_cli.py", line 53, in main
es.search_query()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/es2csv.py", line 26, in f_retry
return f(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/es2csv.py", line 126, in search_query
res = self.es_conn.search(**search_args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/utils.py", line 152, in _wrapped
return func(*args, params=params, headers=headers, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/__init__.py", line 1663, in search
body=body,
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 392, in perform_request
raise e
 elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400, u'search_phase_execution_exception', 
u'compile error')
```

Anything I am missing or doing wrong .Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar w/ `es2csv` but your unfurled query looks like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "script_fields": {
    "field_name": {
      "script": {
        "source": "calculations",  <--
        "lang": "painless"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You're getting the compilation error because `calculations` is a globally undefined variable. So either change it to `doc.calculations.value` or similar but I suspect that it's an array of values anyways, in which case you may rather want to use `"_source": "calculations"` instead of a `script_field` returning just `calculations`:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "_source": "calculations"
}
```

In a more concise form:

```
es2csv  -u http://localhost:9200/ -r -q '{"query":{"match_all":{}},"_source":"calculations"}' ...
```

The `match_all` query can be left out entirely:

```
es2csv  -u http://localhost:9200/ -r -q '{"_source":"calculations"}' ...
```

Comment: i removed `match_all` calculation is like this "script_fields":{"value": {"script": {"source": "doc['column_name'].value/1024.00/1024.00/1024.00","lang": "painless"

Comment: Please provide the full context next time. Anyways, there's nothing wrong with the above so try running the query directly and see if it throws the same error.

Comment: Query is running fine in dev tools